# Trouble getting regex to work with grep/sed

Tags: regex, bash, shell, sed, grep

I've been working on a script to update the PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER in a pbxproj file with a new value using a build script. The regex I've come up with selects everything between 'PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER = ' and any text following up to 2 occurrences of '.' which is what I want.

The regex I've put together to find these occurences is shown here:

```
(?<=PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER = )([a-zA-Z0-9_]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9_]+){0,2})
```

I've tested it with a validator here: https://regex101.com/r/jUhJm7/1

To save time, here's a screenshot with the regex applied and the green portions selected as desired, so the regex seems to be working and recognizes the bundle id portion of the following examples as expected:
[image: Regex Validated]

The issue I'm experiencing is that when using this regex with grep, grep -e, egrep, or sed it doesn't seem to be working in the same manner. I would like to use sed to run the string replacement and have tried the following methods to achieve this:

```
# variable definitions
BUNDLE_ID='mynew.bundle.id'
PBXFILE="$SRCROOT/myproject.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj"

# check if the test bundle id is currently in the file
if grep -Fq "REPLACEABLE_BUNDLE_ID" $PBXFILE; then

    # this commented version works as expected as it's using simple string replacement
    #sed -i '' "s/REPLACEABLE_BUNDLE_ID/$BUNDLE_ID/g" $PBXFILE

    # these are the versions of the regex I've tried with sed #

    # basic version working in validator & testing with sublime text regex engine
    (?<=PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER = )([a-zA-Z0-9_]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9_]+){0,2})
    # added extra parentheses around product id first portion
    (?<=(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER = ))([a-zA-Z0-9_]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9_]+){0,2})
    # escaped version
    \(?<=PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER = \)\([a-zA-Z0-9_]+\(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\){0,2}\)


    # try replacing the current bundle id using the regex
    sed -i -E '' "s/I put the regex here/$BUNDLE_ID/g" $PBXFILE
fi
```

I'm fairly new with regex and have not used sed before. I've read about extended regular expressions here: http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Regular.html#uh-12 and feel like I'm just failing to put the pieces together properly.

Comment: different tools support different flavors of regex... sed supports BRE/ERE which doesn't have lookarounds or unnamed capture groups etc... use `perl` instead.. or use capture groups and back-reference... suggest to remove the image and regex101 related stuff from question.. just add sample text (no image) and output for that

Comment: @Sundeep thanks for your input, I got sed working but I might end up doing this with perl or ruby yet. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this for GNU sed (use `-E` for unix):

```
$ sed -r "s/(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER = )[a-zA-Z0-9_]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9_]+){0,2}/\1${BUNDLE_ID}/"
```

for example:

```
$ cat test.txt 
PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER = com.test.mybundle.keyboard;
PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER = com.test.mybundle.iMessage;
PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER = com.test;
PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER = replaceable;
$ BUNDLE_ID='mynew.bundle.id'
$ sed -r "s/(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER = )[a-zA-Z0-9_]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9_]+){0,2}/\1${BUNDLE_ID}/" test.txt 
PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER = mynew.bundle.id.keyboard;
PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER = mynew.bundle.id.iMessage;
PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER = mynew.bundle.id;
PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER = mynew.bundle.id;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, while it didn't directly solve my issue it did set me on the right path and I now have sed working from my bash script and doing what I was trying to get it to do. I had to drop the -r and use -i '' along with -E and using your formatting. Here's what ended up working for me:

    sed -i '' -E "s/(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER = )[a-zA-Z0-9_]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9_]+){0,3}(.*)/\1${BUNDLE_ID}\2\3/" $PBXFILE